# I have created a textbox in html how to get the answers on that search?

Tags: html

Hi my question is how do I put things into the code so if I search for it in the textbox it will show the results from for example wikipedia?

This is the code for the textbox.

```
<head></head>
<body>
<form name="test">
<input type="text" name="search">
</form>
</body>
```

I use the program brackets and if i run it it gives me a textbox. if i want to search for something it obviously gives me nothing.

it just resets. how do i import the information from wikipedia so it will be shown if i search for it?

its kind of like the coding challenge for the wikipedia API (Coding challenge #75) from the coding train.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You probably wanna google `What is an api`, `how do i use an api`, and `how do i use the wikipedia api with javascript`

Comment: ok thank you... i use html though, not javascript... sorry i'm still really bad in coding so excuse me

Answer (score 0):

In the below example, this is not what you are really looking for, but this may help you to get it.

```
<form name="test" action="https://www.google.com/search/" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q">
<input type="submit">
 </form>
```

> for using api like things you must need some basic JavaScript functionality. And sometimes some basic server site knowledge too!

Comment: Hi there! I think thats what I am looking for. So I used your Code but when I tried it there just came this message: 
404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /search/?q=Google was not found on this server. That’s all we know.